# How do I create a specific version of Django Project in Pycharm( virtual environment)

Tags: python, django, pycharm, virtualenv

such as My Python is 3.6.8，I want to create Django 1.11.8 project In virtual environment？How should I do？ Used virtualenv

1、I create Django Project Under virtual environment in Pycharm，the Django version is auto latest
2、I try Create Django Project by Bash line，but when I open the Project by Pycharm，that is not in virtual environment

Answer (score 0):

Create a virtual environment
I used python 3.8 you can use your required python interpreter version.
python3.8 -m venv venv

2. Activate venv virtual environment.
   source venv/bin/activate
   Install Django

**Now you can install Django by specifying the version.**

pip3 install django==2.2
or
pip3 install django==3.2 # **your required version**

2. Create a django project.
   django-admin startproject mysite
3. Run the server.
   python manage.py runserver